# How to use gcsfuse allow_other option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, gcsfuse

How should I write the command in Google Cloud SSH session to a Ubuntu instance? I tried `gcsfuse <bucket> <mount point> --allow_other`, it gives me an error that gcsfuse works exactly with two arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want

```
gcsfuse -o allow_other <bucket> <mount_point>
```

But please consider whether you really need this option, and only use it if you know what you're doing. It overrides [security restrictions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions) from fuse that are in place for a reason.

Comment: Correct answer! I would only add that one has to make sure that _user_allow_other_ is uncommented in /etc/fuse.conf if one intends to run the _gcsfuse_ command as a non-root user.